# Calculate a running value across columns in power query

Tags: powerquery

i overcame a previous hurdle via checking here - thank you.

But now my next issue is...  I have managed to build the table shown below, where the first 3 columns are coming from a first data source, and the column headers from column 4 onwards are dynamic and added as per the content of a list --> for now, via list.accumulate, i create them as empty (step 1).

current outcome:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J5z6.png)

This is the current code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblTestData"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"characteristic", type text}, {"initial value", type number}, {"start", type date}}),
    Custom1 = List.Accumulate(rngMakeSpan, #"Changed Type", (state, current) => Table.AddColumn(state, current, each null))
in
    Custom1
```

What i am trying to achieve is that the dynamically added columns are now filled with a calculation that takes (step 2):

"initial value" + (0.05 * date difference between "start" and relevant column header)

I assume this is again a list.accumulate, and this would replace the "each null" step in the current list.accumate i already have that creates the dynamic columns...

desired outcome:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPhnZ.png)

Comment: Your desired outcome does not make sense to me. I am assuming your dates are formatted `DMY`. If that is the case, then the Second added column would be `01-Jul-2022`. Start is `01-Jun-2022`. The date difference is `30` days.  `0.05 * 30 = 1.5`. Initial `2` + `1.5` = `3.5` but your desired outcome shows `2.05`. Please clarify.

Comment: Apologies... im using DateDif(xx,xx,"M") in Excel to mock it up.  The difference is in months, not days, because the factor of evolution is a monthly factor.  I should have made that clear!  So every month the quality characteristic changes with that factor - so we are calculating a "prediction" of the value towards future months...

Answer (score 0):

Power Query does not include a native `Date.Diff` function (or even `Duration.Months`) but, since you are apparently adding "Date Columns" at monthly intervals, we can use that to add the column and it's calculation in the same step using `List Accumulate`.

Please examine the code and pay attention to the comments for where you might need to make some modifications to apply to your real data:

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table19"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"characteristic", type text}, 
        {"initial value", type number}, {"start", type date}}),

//Not sure how you determine first column headed by dates
// but they seem to be at monthly intervals
// so I just hard coded what I saw
// but you can use a different algorithm
    #"Col1" = #date(2022,6,1),

    #"Add Date Columns" = 
        List.Accumulate(
            {0..6}, //number of "Date Columns" to add
            #"Changed Type",
            (s, c)=> Table.AddColumn(s, Date.ToText(Date.AddMonths(#"Col1",c),"dd/MM/yyyy"), 
                each [initial value] + c*0.05, type number))
    
in
    #"Add Date Columns"
```

***Original Table***
[image]

***Results***
[image]